# How to avoid duplicate values while retrieving from database in django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I need to avoid duplicate values while retrieving from database in django. I am having the result dictionary as list.

```
 queryset = [{'name':'shankar','Age':'24'},{'name':'Manoj','Age':'26'},   {'name':'shankar','Age':'25'}]
```

I need to display the value in dropdown list as the value **shankar and Manoj**. I am retrieving the value like the query below

```
 queryset = Books.objects.all()
```

Now i want to avoid the duplicate value while displaying dropdown list in template page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They aren't really "duplicate" because of the age discrepancy...How do you want to choose between the two?

Comment: So then i need to avoid display "name" value more times. is there anyother way to do it. am jus searching anyotherway to avoid while display in built-in template tags

Answer (score 1):

use

```
queryset = Books.objects.all().distinct('name')
```

See docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct):

> "..On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in
>   order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should
>   apply. This translates to a SELECT DISTINCT ON SQL query. Here’s the
>   difference. For a normal distinct() call, the database compares each
>   field in each row when determining which rows are distinct. For a
>   distinct() call with specified field names, the database will only
>   compare the specified field names."

Comment: no need to pass it as a keyword argument, just pass the name of each field. See my answer and the docs for an example. By the way, are you using PostgreSQL?

Comment: yes.. when i pass "name" field in distinct function, it shouldn't get the name value from database.

Comment: distinct is used to filter the records. In the returned queryset, the objects have all the fields (name and Age), as normal.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer solves your question (accept it or indicate why not)

Comment: when i use distinct keyword, it shouldn't get the value of "name". I need to get the value one time. it shows the output like "[{'name':u' ','Age':'24'},{'name':u' ','Age':'26'},{'name':u' ','Age':'25'}]" . Anyother idea??

Answer (score 0):

Use values() instead all() method in queryset:

```
queryset = Book.objects.values('name').distinct()
```

And in your template:

```
<select>
{% for obj in object_list %}
<option>{{ obj.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: I have done it with the help of values_list('name').distinct(). But it shows the error while displaying. it shows Attribute Error: 'unicode object has no attribute pk'